# Dismiss Google payment sheet

Tags: google-tasks-api, google-pay

I have unique business logic requirement where I need to cancel or stop user from proceeding with Google pay if timer that is running in the background runs out.

Suppose user clicked Google pay button, then we use

```
AutoResolveHelper.resolveTask<PaymentData>(futurePayTask, this, LOAD_PAYMENT_DATA_REQUEST_CODE)
```

This should return `onactivityresult` if user performs cancel or success but I want to forcefully cancel if timer runs out.

Google sheet open as shown here:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I will post my answer after discussion with official google pay team, they told its not possible, so I myself just put one alert dialog before showing payment sheet informing user to finish transaction within stipulated time